# Org agenda how to define a customized command

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Basically, I'm trying to filter all the items with tag of :Dually: but not excluding ones with both :Dually: and :T:, the attached picture shows the questions better, please have a look. Many thanks.[image]

Comment: You may be interested in Googling a bit for **"org-agenda-skip-entry-if"** **regexp**  Create your `(org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'regexp ...` and try constructing a regexp used to isolate what you wish to exclude.

Comment: This can be done the other way too -- i.e., `'notregexp` and construct the appropriate regexp for just one tag.